# centering pgfplots in a standalone PDF file

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, standalone, tikz-positioning, sticky-labels

I am using pgfplots to plot figure as a single pdf file, and then include it into the main latex code for the document. A simple example is as following.

```
\documentclass[
border={0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}, % left bottom right top
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        x  y1 y2
        1  1  2
        2  4  5
        3  2  3
        4  6  7
        5  5  6
        6  6  7
    }{\curves}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [color=black,grid=major,use units, xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
                legend style={draw=none,fill=none,legend image post style={scale=1}, font=\scriptsize}, legend cell align={left}, legend pos=north west,]
                \addplot[dashed,draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=1, ]{\curves};
                \addplot[       draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=2, ]{\curves};
                \legend{curve1, curve2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then, a single pdf file for the figure is generated as following.

[image]

As can be seen that, due to the existence of ylabel, the main figure is to the right of the whole pdf picture. Then, when I insert it into my main latex code, the figure will also be to the right of the page. Ideally, I want to generate a picture like the following (in which the grey area was also a part of the whole picture). Then, the main figure was able to be at the centre of the whole picture("x" stays at the centre).

[image]

I hope to consult that, are there some methods to achieve this?

Comment: A manual solution would be to set the right border to 11mm: `\documentclass[border={0mm 0mm 11mm 0mm}]{standalone}`.

Comment: I do not think you want what you describe. The standalone will work the same way as if the code was directly in you main document. -so nothing is needed. Section 4.20 "The Picture’s Size: Bounding Box and Clipping" in the manual describes how to manipulate the bounding box. -if you really need it. -but it is not normal to make the bounding box bigger than the content, but smaller (it will not clip the content). E.g. `\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
              (current axis.south west)
    rectangle (current axis.north east);` as in the manual.